# mac Catalina PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Tags: macos, permissions, spyder, macos-catalina

After installing the macOS Catalina update, I can't work with my program anymore (Spyder GUI). I want to read files which are not in the current workspace and perform operations on them. When reading the file directory, I get this error:

> PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: {file directory}

Files inside the current workspace are fine.

Comment: Please read [this](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/). It could help to solve your problem.

Comment: I am also getting same error.